# Mdx Query Problem

Tags: mdx, members

Hi
I m working on mdx query ,and i thought i solved a problem but....
I ve created a calculated member

```
iif(
  isleaf([DimensionArtikujDG].[DimensionArtikujDG].CurrentMember),
         ([Measures].[Sasia])*(1/[Measures].[Koeficienti]),
        Sum(
          Descendants(
            [DimensionArtikujDG].DimensionArtikujDG].CurrentMember,,LEAVES),
            ([Measures].[Sasia])*(1/[Measures].[Koeficienti])
        )
)
```

When `[DimensionArtikujDG].[DimensionArtikujDG]` is inside the pivot table
it works fine.
When i take this dimension at the reports filter area and filter
two or three elements the total in report area does not change.
It remains the total without the filters being applied.
Don t know if i explained it correctly.
Would apprceiate any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the value of your currentMember when evaluating the expression. A way to understand what is going on is changing your expression to :

[DimensionArtikujDG].[DimensionArtikujDG].CurrentMember.name

As you're using a set in your slicer (aka WHERE) currentMember is not well defined (in icCube we throw an error). Maybe the server you're using is taking the defaultmember (likely [All]).

Solution: this will depend on the Olap Server you're using. As a hint look how to define a special rollup for your dimension.